# цифры в круге на css3

Tags: css3, css-circle

Скриптом в круг добавляются цифры, и когда цифра становится больше 9 и больше 99, то круг плющится - получается уже диск. Подскажите, пжл., как стилями можно сделать так, чтобы круг всегда оставался кругом при любом количестве цифр.
https://jsfiddle.net/sbmmex4h/

```css
.span1, .span2, .span3{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: .3em .65em;
}
```

```html
<span class="span1">1</span><br/><br/>
<span class="span2">10</span><br/><br/>
<span class="span3">100</span>
```

Comment: повторите пробему в фидле пожалуйста, круг можно нарисовать многими способами и не понятно какой способ вам нужен

Comment: @JurijJazdanov , span  будет один и в него будет вставляться разные цифры(предположительно до 1к)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> данный пример не подходит под мою задачу, так как ячейка меньше 2em.
>   Хотелось бы чтобы фифры не примыкали к краям круга

тогда такой вариант:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
  padding: 0em 0.65em;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class=container><span class="span"></span><span class=text>1</span></div>
<div class=container><span class="span"></span><span class=text>10</span></div>
<div class=container><span class="span"></span><span class=text>10000</span></div>
```

Comment: - спасибо, то, что надо...

Answer (score 1):

Просто укажите размер, а отступ уберите:

```
  width:2em;
  height:1em;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
```

(`1em` - высота шрифта)

```css
.span1, .span2, .span3{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em  0;
  width:2em;
  height:1em;
  
}
```

```html
<span class="span1">1</span><br/><br/>
<span class="span2">10</span><br/><br/>
<span class="span3">100</span><br/><br/>
<span class="span3">1000</span>
```

Comment: а если вставить цифру 10000?

Comment: данный пример не подходит под мою задачу, так как ячейка меньше 2em. Хотелось бы чтобы фифры не примыкали к краям круга.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.notification-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.notification-container__text {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f56019;
  border-radius: 22px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="notification-container">
  <span class="notification-container__text">10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]